# Swift: modalTransitionStyle = .FlipHorizontal (right to left)

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller, ios8, flip

a Swift problem on XCODE 6,1 iOS8 i can't solve:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    modalTransitionStyle = .FlipHorizontal
```

That works amazingly, except i want to flip on the other direction

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a custom modal transition for that (the SDK provides a default behaviour for `. FlipHorizontal` which is the one you describe - this is explained in the [doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/UIModalTransitionStyle)).

Have a look at this [github repo](https://github.com/sergiocampama/SpringAndBlurDemo) for an example of how you can use a transition delegate and an animation controller to create your own modal transition.